# iOS - Cannot deploy to iOS 6.1 Simulator or set Deployment Target to iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, ios6

My app got rejected because it crashes on the iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1. So I was trying to test on this version, but I realized that my xCode for this app does not have the option to run the emulator in iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1

How could I make it run in that configuration?

My current target is 6.0 iPhone. When I try to make the "deployment target" 6.1 I don't have that option. It only goes to 6.0...but the xCode for my other app does have the 6.1 option. What should I change in order to enable that?

Thanks!

Comment: The deployment target has nothing to do with which simulator to use. The deployment target sets the MINIMUM version of iOS required for your app to run, so if you set it to 6.1 then only people with iOS 6.1 or newer will be able to install/run your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update to Xcode 4.6 which includes the 6.1 simulator and SDK. Do this in the AppStore.

If you ever need to install a different simulator within Xcode go to Preferences and then the Downloads sections

[image]

Comment: thank you - I currently have cCode 4.5.2 ...on my other app I was able to install the 6.1 emulator somehow, but in my downloads section of preferences for this app, for some reason 6.1 is not there. Would you know how to make it appear there so I can download it?

Comment: I am not sure if you can run the 6.1 simulator or SDK with Xcode 4.5.2, it comes with 4.6. Is there a reason you can't update to 4.6?

Comment: I just double chacked and I only have 6.1 available on my xCode...looks like I need to update xCode.  Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain how I can update xCode? I am a bit worried about breaking some existing configurations so I want to know I am doing it right.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on being able to download old simulators

Comment: @Genadinik the update process is pretty straight forward, you just press Update in the AppStore. You really don't have control over what happens now that Apple runs it through the AppStore. You can take a copy of your currently installed version before updating to insure nothing goes awry and you lose something from your previous install. http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/how-to-install-and-manage-multiple-versions-of-xcode.html